# MySqlDateTime in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime, casting

I am trying to do a comparison of a MySqlDateTime object to another MySqlDateTime object, each from two different tables.  I am trying to do all of this inside a LINQ query, ex:

```
        var prodRowFindQuery =
            from x in production.AsEnumerable()
            where x.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date") == row.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date") &&
                  x.Field<String>("device_id3") == row.Field<String>("device_id3")
            select x;
```

This gives me a compiler error:

**Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime' and 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime'**

So then I try this:

```
        var prodRowFindQuery =
            from x in production.AsEnumerable()
            where x.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date").ToString() == row.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date").ToString() &&
                  x.Field<String>("device_id3") == row.Field<String>("device_id3")
            select x;
```

Now it compiles, but I get a run-time error:

**Specified cast is not valid.**

Stack Trace:

```
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.DataTableComparer.CompareTables.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Data.DataRow x = {System.Data.DataRow}) Line 34 C#  
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Data.DataRow>.MoveNext() + 0x9c bytes   
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.DataTableComparer.CompareTables(System.Data.DataTable aggregate = {System.Data.DataTable}, System.Data.DataTable production = {System.Data.DataTable}) Line 39 + 0x8b bytes   C#  
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.DbTransferWindowViewModel.CopyTestReliability() Line 177 + 0x94 bytes C#  
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.DelegateCommand.Execute() Line 78 + 0x1f bytes    C#  
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.DelegateCommand.System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute(object parameter = null) Line 158 + 0xa bytes   C#  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() + 0xaf bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0x117 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x56 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x270 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender = {System.Windows.Controls.Button}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent) + 0x183 bytes     
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target) + 0x56 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) + 0x270 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender = {System.Windows.Controls.Button}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}) + 0x14e bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}) + 0x64 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() + 0x431 bytes     
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport) + 0xfd bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel) + 0x410 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd = 396436, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg = WM_LBUTTONUP, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr lParam = 34472260, ref bool handled = false) + 0x388 bytes    
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x7c bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x14a bytes     
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x80 bytes      
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x5e bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler = null) + 0x47 bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x2bc bytes  
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0x140 bytes      
[Native to Managed Transition]    
[Managed to Native Transition]    
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x112 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x17a bytes      
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x67 bytes   
IthacaDbTransferUtil.exe!IthacaDbTransferUtil.App.Main() + 0x77 bytes   C#  
[Native to Managed Transition]    
[Managed to Native Transition]    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x5a bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes     
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes      
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x51 bytes     
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Another example I have tried:

```
            var prodRowFindQuery =
                from x in production.AsEnumerable()
                where Convert.ToDateTime(x.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date")) == Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<MySqlDateTime>("date")) &&
                      x.Field<String>("device_id3") == row.Field<String>("device_id3")
                select x;
```

Still raises a run-time error:

**Specified cast is not valid.**

Another example:

```
            var prodRowFindQuery =
                from x in production.AsEnumerable()
                where x.Field<DateTime>("date") == row.Field<DateTime>("date") &&
                      x.Field<String>("device_id3") == row.Field<String>("device_id3")
                select x;
```

Same run-time error:

**Specified cast is not valid.**

Somebody said something about "date" not being a MySqlDateTime type, for fun, here's the proof that it is:

```
            var prodRowFindQuery =
                from x in production.AsEnumerable()
                where x.Field<String>("date") == row.Field<String>("date") &&
                      x.Field<String>("device_id3") == row.Field<String>("device_id3")
                select x;
```

Run-time exception:

**Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime' to type 'System.String'.**

I have tried a few other things and nothing works for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards,

Kyle

Comment: Please add the stack-trace of the exception you get.

Comment: .ToString() may not be supported without format operands. have you tried .Equals()?

Comment: Where is the exact location of the exception when it is raised? Is it on the `.Field<...>()` call?

Comment: MD.Unicorn:  The location this exception gets raised is when i put the "prodRowFindQuery" inside a foreach loop.  This exception is raised upon the very first loop of this foreach loop; it doesn't even run because it raises the exception as it tries to pull out the "date" field

Comment: You say "linq", but don't specify what flavor.  Is this Entity Framework with a MySql back-end?  Linq-to-Sql?  Something MySql specific?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

In pseudo code, here is how I did it:

1. create two new DataTables
2. do a select on one DataTable, pulling in all data needed for the table
3. clone the table by doing this:

   ```
       officialTable = temporaryTable.Clone();
   ```
4. cast the column by doing this:

   ```
       officialTable.Columns["date"].DataType = typeof(String);
   ```
5. either iterate through the table rows, copying one row to the other; OR do another select statement to get all the data again, but this time, the "data" column will be automatically casted to a  instead of .
6. dispose of the old DataTable

I hope this helps somebody else out.

Answer (score 0):

The highest probability is that the `"date"` field of `DataRow` is not of type `MySqlDateTime`, or `"device_id3"` field is not of type `string`.

Comment: Heres a little more info that may help out:  I know for a fact that "device_id3" is definitely a string.  As for date, Im not totally sure.  I always get MySqlDateTime casting errors which I find odd because when I query that column, I say "CAST(date as CHAR(50)) AS date" to cast the DateTime field into a string field before it ever gets to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no equality operator defined for a MySQLDateTime you can either define one yourself, or convert this to a standard .NET datetime object before doing comparisons.

Comment: see the new code examples i posted after the stack trace in the original post.  How do i successfully convert from a MySqlDateTime to a System.DateTime inside a LINQ query?